# Aligning Text boxes Django

Tags: python, django

This is my registration form:

[image: Registration Form]

I am trying to align all of the text boxes. This is my form code;

Forms.py

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True, label = "Email:")
    username = forms.CharField(required=True, label = "Username:")
    first_name = forms.CharField(required=True, label = "First Name:")
    last_name = forms.CharField(required=True, label = "Last Name:")
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, required=True, 
    label = "Password:")
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput, required=True, 
    label = "Confirm Password:")


class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = {
        'password2',
        'username',
        'first_name',
        'last_name',
        'email',
        'password1'
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to understand that the output that Django gave you here is html, and you'll have to style it with css.

So you'll need to understand how you can style your forms with html and css, it is not really something you do in Django. (Although you can give custom attributes to HTML elements in Django, and then use those attributes to reference those HTML elements in your css. The tutorial below talks about this under the heading: 'Using Custom HTML Attributes')

Below I'll share a link to a tutorial that has helped me understand how to customize how forms render. This should explain a lot of what I am trying to explain.

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/article/2017/08/19/how-to-render-django-form-manually.html

Comment: If this answers solved your problem, could you select it as the correct answer please?

Comment: The link you provided was very useful to me in this aspect, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Although [@rik-schoonbeek's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49138817) is correct and, probably, preferable, there *is* a way to align the text boxes using django only (i.e. without CSS).

The OP does not show a template, but it looks like the form is rendered using `{{ form.as_p }}` in the template.

In that case, the quickest way to achieve text box alignment, using django only, would be to use `{{ form.as_table }}` (or just `{{ form }}`).

For example:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <table>
        {{ form.as_table }}
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

Obviously some CSS would help to make the result more appealing.